# Why do I get a 'list index out of range' error here when creating an instance of a class?

Tags: python, list

I have a text file with several tab-separated columns of information about articles from a blog. Each row in the file represents a single article, and by splitting a line up around the tabs, you can extract an ID number, a title, a paragraph and other things about that particular article.

For example:

```
id   articleID    title    paragraph
1    4    Motorola prototypes from Frog    Some cool looking concepts for phones...
```

So, I've written a piece of code which turns this into a list called *articlesFileList* where each line is an element in the list, and this works exactly as you'd expect.

```
file = open("articles.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
file.readline() # (Skip first line)
articlesFile = file.read()
articlesFileList = articlesFile.split("\n")
```

After this, I then split the lines into their individual columns and create *Article* instances which have attributes for the id, title, paragraph etc.

`for line in articlesFileList:
    columns = line.split("\t")
    article = Article(columns[0], columns[2], columns[3])
    articleList = []
    articleList.append(article)`

But this code then throws this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Python\RBTrends\RBTrendsAnalysis.py", line 55, in <module>
 articlesList = createArticles(articlesFileList)
 File "E:\Python\RBTrends\RBTrendsAnalysis.py", line 32, in createArticles
 article = Article(columns[0], columns[2], columns[3])
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

My first thought was that maybe the *columns* list didn't contain the correct information, so I added the following code to check what was in that list:

```
for i in columns:
    print(i)
```

...and the list appears absolutely perfect. Each column of each line is printed correctly. I've even tried to print each index of the list just to see if they could be accessed 'by hand', and they can. The program with accessing the list elements seems to just be when creating instances of a class.

Any help/explanation would be very much appreciated as this is an error that has been confusing me for a while now.

Comment: Instead of doing this from scratch I would recommend using the csvreader module.

Comment: What you've pasted contains space separation, not tabs. This may be a pasting error... But it would also cause the exact error you describe.

Comment: @Wooble Yes, I should have stated in the post.. The real file has tab separation, but here I just wrote out by hand the first two lines of the file with 4 spaces instead of tabs because I couldn't type tabs into the text box.

Comment: Well, you've got a line in the file without the right number of tabs (possibly a blank line).

Comment: Instead of printing all of the output at once to verify it, print each `line` and `columns` immediately before the line of code that causes the error. That will be more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `columns` list is not containing enough items and fails retrieving nonexistent item.

I can imagine two reasons:

- your file contains empty line, it can be the last one after final "\n".
- you lines are not separated by tabs, but spaces.

To test this, I would add before the line where it fails

```
assert len(columns) >= 4
```

As you are using index 3, you need to have list with 4 items. This line will throw an exception in case, the list is shorter.